# Cant find and click on conformation alert in webbrowser. How to find all alerts?

Tags: python, selenium, popup, alert

I just can't get the following conformation alert to be confirmed in pyhton /selenium. I would like to press the "Citrix Workspace Launcher öffnen" button.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pywinauto
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys


username = "xxx"
password = "yyyy"

url = "hy"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\gdg")
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "Enter user name").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwd").send_keys(password)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "Log_On").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Citrix Workspace-App ermitteln").click()
time.sleep(2)

#here comes the Conformation alert
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();  #this doesnt work
```

[Here is how the alert look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL54W.png)

Comment: try `driver.switch_to.alert.accept()` and `driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()`

Comment: Many thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't work, I tried it. Get the message: selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert. It doesn't seem to be a alert notification after all. A javascript I can't inspect with inspect tools of browser

Answer (score 0):

This is the soluton to click on left button!

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press(Key.left)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
```